# How to retrieve help topic content in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my Eclipse RCP application I need programmatically retrieve content of all help topics in system (including topics from remote help).

I can get list of all topic URLs using following code

```
Toc[] tocs = HelpPlugin.getTocManager().getTocs(Platform.getNL());
for (Toc toc : tocs) {
    ITopic[] topics = toc.getTopics();
    for (ITopic topic : topics) {
        System.out.println("label: " + topic.getLabel() + ", href: " + topic.getHref());
        // process subtopics topic.getSubtopics()
    }
}
```

But here I can get hrefs for topics relative to documentation server base URL.

For example in case of below screenshot:
URL for "Eclipse platform overview" topic is:
'127.0.0.1:54821/help/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/intro/overview.htm?cp=0_0'.

I can get '/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/intro/overview.htm' part using above code.

The question is how to get base URL (127.0.0.1:54821)?

[image]

Comment: `HelpPlugin` and `Toc` are both internal classes and are not part of the Eclipse API [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). They can be changed without notice.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if there is way to do it without usage of internal classes.